# Ubuntu 14.04 dual boot install

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, grub2, wubi

I have Windows 7(64 bit) installed on my system along with Ubuntu 12.04. I want to upgrade to 14.04 version of ubuntu but since I do not have a good internet connection I am unable to upgrade it using update manager. I somehow managed to get a .iso file downloaded. Is there some way i can upgrade using a cd or usb drive? 
I am not sure which boot loader i have. I installed 12.04 using wubi installer. I dont want to mess up my system so please someone help me regarding this??

Answer (score 0):

Now if you burn your image and boot from CD/DVD it should have (and offer) Upgrade Installation scenario.
[image]

Comment: Are you sure there would be an option to upgrade from 12.04 to 14.04 ? Because i read ubuntu blogs and they tell that upgrades are done in systematic release manner ie 12.04 -> 13.04 -> 14.04

Comment: Which version does your current 12.04 normally offer to upgrade to via internet?

Comment: I think i allows me to upgrade to 13.04

Answer (score 0):

You can create a bootable Ubuntu USB from any OS (Windows or Ubuntu) following the instructions described [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick). After that you can boot from the USB and install it as a fresh installation. You can choose to upgrade the current system. If you are using the same architecture then it's fine. If you are upgrading to 64-bit (or downgrading to 32-bit) I recommend that you run fresh installation because I had so many problems and just wasted more space.

Comment: I am upgrading it on 64 bit framework. Previously also it was the same 64 bits. Will this fresh installation have nay effect on my bootloader because i installed previously using windows installer wubi.

Comment: Your boot loader should be fine. Also you can modify the grub later as you pleas.

Comment: Ok thankyou. i will try this meathod and update here regarding the result.